# view('bladeFile', $data)->render() keeps returning error that render() method does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

```
"Call to undefined method Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\CompilerEngine::render() (View: \/home\/vagrant\/code\/resources\/views\/order\/invoice.blade.php)",
```

I am trying to get the html code from my view into a variable to later use it, but it keeps giving me an error that render() method is undefined. When I remove the variables within the view an leave only html it works fine. This is how I try to call it:

```
$content = view('order.invoice', ['order' => $order])->render();
```

Comment: Hi, can you print the contents of `view('order.invoice', ['order' => $order])`?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ZCZQphTQ

Comment: Your Question has to be self-contained. Meaning all the information needs to be within this Question itself. A link is not sufficient. The code you post here should be the minimum amount of code needed to understand the problem, see [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)